# Android app: How to create a new window?

Tags: android, window, screen, new-operator

I'm pretty new to Android applications. What I have at the moment is an "app", which displays a login screen, and users can log in. What I want is, if the login is correct, to "forward" or open a new window, where users can change some settings etc... So really, I only need help with creating a new window.
How would one do that? Make a new activity perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, you just start a new activity with startActivity()

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setClass(this,SecondActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

**This** means the class you come from, so the current one. SecondActivity is the activity you want to start.

Comment: yes, I know what **this** means, i've done oop before. Anyhow, how can I add a layout to this activity now?

Comment: In the second activity, you just use setContentView() to use an xml layout in the activity.